# Rotating an HTML element with mouse (or mouseevent) with CSS zoom applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transforms

I've found an example of rotating an HTML element in an old SO question:

http://jsfiddle.net/superasn/w48rsvp2/

Unforunatately as soon as I apply any zoom (style="zoom:0.5") to the parent element the rotation becomes wonky.

http://jsfiddle.net/superasn/mv2oqL36/2/ (with zoom of 0.5 and offset of 500px on parent element)

The code for rotation is like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // the same as yours.
  function rotateOnMouse(e, pw) {
      var offset = pw.offset();
      var center_x = (offset.left) + ($(pw).width() / 2);
      var center_y = (offset.top) + ($(pw).height() / 2);
      var mouse_x = e.pageX;
      var mouse_y = e.pageY;
      var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
      var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 100;
      //            window.console.log("de="+degree+","+radians);
      $(pw).css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
      $(pw).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
      $(pw).css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
      $(pw).css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
  }

  $('.drop div img').mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents the dragging of the image.
    $(document).bind('mousemove.rotateImg', function(e2) {
      rotateOnMouse(e2, $('.drop div img'));
    });
  });

  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    $(document).unbind('mousemove.rotateImg');
  });
});
```

I think the `rotateOnMouse` function needs to factor the CSS zoom of parent somehow but I can't figure it out.

**My questions is what changes I need to make in `rotateOnMouse` function to calculate `degree` variable after zoom?**

Comment: P.S. I've tried diving `center_x` and `center_y` with zoom (so `center_x/2` for zoom 0.5) and it makes it work a little but the rotation isn't very smooth.

Comment: Updating the center during rotation made it wonky when hovering the image, even without the zoom. Seems to work better when defining it beforehand, accounting for the zoom level is rather simple - use it as an extra factor when calculating the center. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/poqcn46L/1/) a demo.

Comment: thanks it does seem to work with the changes you've made!

Comment: No problem, I noticed `zoom` doesn't actually work in Firefox but I don't see any real adverse effect either. Might be worth checking into though, possibly use `scale` instead.

Comment: If i offset the parent by a few pixels then it doesn't work.. see here http://jsfiddle.net/superasn/mv2oqL36/. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Not as simple as I thought it was apparently, my earlier approach seemed to be working (and logical) but it was likely a fluke. The clue is actually in the `pageX` and `pageY` events I think. Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k1ce0gpd/). It's pretty terrible on Firefox now though.